# tensorflow: load checkpoint

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.x

I've been training a model which looks a bit like:

```
base_model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(weights=weights, include_top=False, input_tensor=input_tensor)

for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPool2D()(base_model.output)

output = tf.keras.Sequential()
output.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='linear'))
output.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='linear'))
output.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='linear'))
output.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='linear'))
output.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='linear'))

return output(x)
```

I setup checkpoints saving with code like:

```
cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=checkpoint_path,
    verbose=1,
    save_weights_only=True,
    save_freq=batch_size*5)
```

Yesterday I started a fit to run for 11 epochs. I'm not sure why, but the machine restarted during the 7th epoch. Naturally I want to resume fitting from the start of epoch 7.

The checkpoint code above created three files:

[image]

The contents of checkpoint are:

```
model_checkpoint_path: "checkpoint"
all_model_checkpoint_paths: "checkpoint"
```

The other two files are binary. I tried to load the checkpoint weights with both:

```
model.load_weights('./2022-03-16_21-10/checkpoints/checkpoint.data-00000-of-00001')
model.load_weights('./2022-03-16_21-10/checkpoints/')
```

Both fail with `NotFoundError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files`.

How can I restore this checkpoint and as a result resume fitting?

I'm using tensorflow 2.4.

Comment: I think that the training restart from the first epoch but with the saved weights from yesterday's training, so with the loss and the accuracy obtained until the 6th epoch. I am also trying to fix this, but after some research on web I think that is necessary to save the model in HDF5 format. I leave you a youtube video showing this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kaQCdv46OBA.
I hope I have been helpful. I will follow this post.

Comment: @marco Coincidentally I watched that video 30 mins before posting this question!

Comment: I think you should just call 
`model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)`
or
`model.load_weights('checkpoint')`
Using the same path you used for saving it.

Also since you want the training to continue from where it stopped: make sure your model gets assigned an optimizer **before** loading the weights. You achive this by calling `model.compile(optimizer=your_optimizer)`

Answer (score 1):

These might help: [Training checkpoints](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoint) and [tf.train.Checkpoint](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Checkpoint). According to the documentation, you should be able to load the model using something like this:

```
model = tf.keras.Model(...)
checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(model)
# Restore the checkpointed values to the `model` object.
checkpoint.restore(save_path)
```

I am not sure it will work if the checkpoint contains other variables. You might have to use `checkpoint.restore(path).expect_partial()`.

You can also check the content that has been saved (according to the documentation) by *Manually inspecting checkpoints* :

```
reader = tf.train.load_checkpoint('./tf_ckpts/')
shape_from_key = reader.get_variable_to_shape_map()
dtype_from_key = reader.get_variable_to_dtype_map()

sorted(shape_from_key.keys())
```